# 百分率比の表示をもう少し見やすくしたいです

Tags: c

データの個数を入力させ、その入力したデータとその要素の合計を順番に出力し、なおかつその百分率比（要素の合計値に対するある要素の割合「ある要素÷要素の合計値✕１００」）を表示するプログラムを作成したのですが、百分率表示の箇所をもう少し見やすくしたいのです。

**作成したプログラム**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* size個 の入力された実数データを 配列の先頭から順番に格納する */
void readDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d 番目? ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
}

/* size個 の実数データが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%lf ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//要素数size の合計値を返す．

double souwa(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    double s;
    s=0.0; 
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        s=s+a[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    double data[1024];
    int size,i;

    printf("データの個数を入力してください：");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    readDoubleArray(data, size);
    printf("順番に出力:");
    printDoubleArray(data, size);
    printf("要素の合計:%lf\n", souwa(data,size));

    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1){
        printf("100分比:");  printf("%lf ",(data[i]/souwa(data,size))*100);
    }   printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**実行結果**

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数を入力してください：3
1 番目? 1.1
2 番目? 1.1
3 番目? 1.1
順番に出力:1.100000 1.100000 1.100000 
要素の合計:3.300000
100分比:33.333333 100分比:33.333333 100分比:33.333333
```

**期待している実行結果**

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数を入力してください：3
1 番目? 1.1
2 番目? 1.1
3 番目? 1.1
順番に出力:1.100000 1.100000 1.100000 
要素の合計:3.300000
100分比:33.333333 33.333333 33.333333
```

このように少し見やすくしたいのですが、どうすればそのような表示になりますか。

Comment: `printf("100分比:");`は`for`ループに入っているのではないですか。

Comment: 「順番に出力:」のところで欲しい結果と似たようなことができているので、その処理を真似すれば良いのですよ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄でも指摘のある通り、結果の表示する箇所を以下の様に修正すればよさそうに見えます。

```c
    printf("100分比:");
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1){
        printf("%lf ",(data[i]/souwa(data,size))*100);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

---

なお、過去の質問でも何度かコメントでアドバイスを残していますが、「コンパイル」とは "ソースコードを実行可能な状態にすること (a.outの生成)" を指します。
あなたが毎回「コンパイル結果」と書いている箇所は、正しくは「(プログラムの) 実行結果」だと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。文printf("１００分比")をforループの中に入れていました。また、以前までコンパイル結果ではなくて、正しくは実行結果だというアドバイスを読み飛ばしておりました。今度気をつけます。